# Rendering different youtube videos on button click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-player

I created a react app where I display different video games and the app decides which game to play. I also have a file where I stored the data of video games. The goal I'm trying to achieve is to render the youtube video trailer of the corresponding video game when clicking on a button while using React Hooks. I've been using the npm package react-player. If someone could help, I'd appreciate it.

This is the code for the Video Game component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, message } from 'antd';
import { Row, Col } from 'antd';
import GameEntry from '../GameEntry';
import Games from '../Games';

function VideoGameSection() {
    const chooseGame = () => {
        var randomGameTitle = [
            'Gears 5',
            'Halo',
            'Hellblade',
            'It takes two',
            'A Plague Tale',
            'Psychonauts',
            'Twelve Minutes',
            'Ori',
            'Streets of Rage',
            'Last of Us',
            'Boodborne',
            'Geenshin Impact',
            'Dragon Ball Z:KAKAROT',
            'Ghost Tsushima',
            'Naruto',
            'Overcooked',
            'Horizon',
            'Tomb Raider',
            'Uncharted',
            'Person 5 Royal',
            'Ratchet',
            'Spider-Man',
        ];

        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomGameTitle.length);

        return message.info(
            'The game you will play is: ' + randomGameTitle[randomIndex] + '.',
        );
    };

    return (
        <div id="video-game" className="block bgGray">
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="titleHolder">
                    <h2>Video Games</h2>
                    <p>A list of current games</p>
                    <div className="site-button-ghost-wrapper">
                        <Button
                            className="gameButton"
                            type="primary"
                            danger
                            ghost
                            onClick={chooseGame}
                        >
                            Pick for me
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Row gutter={[16, 24]}>
                    {Games.map((videogame, i) => (
                        <Col span={8}>
                            <GameEntry
                                id={i}
                                key={i}
                                title={videogame.title}
                                imgURL={videogame.imgURL}
                                description={videogame.console}
                            />
                        </Col>
                    ))}
                </Row>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default VideoGameSection;
```

This is the code for my game entry component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Card, Button, Modal } from 'antd';
import YoutubeSection from './Home/YoutubeSection';

const { Meta } = Card;

function GameEntry(props) {
    const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);

    const showModal = () => {
        setIsModalVisible(true);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setIsModalVisible(false);
    };

    const handleCancel = () => {
        setIsModalVisible(false);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Card
                className="gameCard"
                hoverable
                cover={<img className="cardImg" alt={props.title} src={props.imgURL} />}
            >
                <div className="cardTitle">
                    <Meta title={props.title} description={props.description} />
                </div>
                <>
                    <Button
                        className="trailerButton"
                        type="primary"
                        block
                        style={{
                            color: '#fff',
                            borderColor: '#fff',
                            backgroundColor: '#e6544f',
                        }}
                        onClick={showModal}
                    >
                        Click for trailer
                    </Button>
                    <Modal
                        title={props.title}
                        width={'725px'}
                        visible={isModalVisible}
                        onOk={handleClose}
                        onCancel={handleCancel}
                    >
                        <YoutubeSection />
                    </Modal>
                </>
            </Card>
        </div>
    );
}

export default GameEntry;
```

This is the code for the youtube component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';

function YoutubeSection(props) {
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <ReactPlayer
                // url={videoTrailer}
                muted={false}
                playing={true}
                controls={true}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default YoutubeSection;
```

example of data file:

```
const Games = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Gears 5',
        imgURL: '../Images/gears-5.jpeg',
        console: 'Xbox',
        videoID: 'SEpWlFfpEkU&t=7s',
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep a single Modal component and use it for that.

**ModalView.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import YoutubeSection from "./YoutubeSection";
import { Modal } from "antd";

const ModalView = ({
  title,
  isModalVisible,
  handleClose,
  handleCancel,
  videoID
}) => {
  return (
    <Modal
      title={title}
      width={"725px"}
      visible={isModalVisible}
      onOk={handleClose}
      onCancel={handleCancel}
    >
      <YoutubeSection videoID={videoID} />
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default ModalView;
```

Move the `ModalView` and its `state`, control functions to the `VideoGameSection`.

**VideoGameSection.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, message } from "antd";
import { Row, Col } from "antd";
import GameEntry from "./GameEntry";
import Games from "./Games";
import ModalView from "./ModalView";

function VideoGameSection() {
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [currentVideoID, setCurrentVideoID] = useState("");

  const showModal = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(false);
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(false);
  };

  const chooseGame = () => {
    var randomGameTitle = [
      "Gears 5",
      "Halo",
      "Hellblade",
      "It takes two",
      "A Plague Tale",
      "Psychonauts",
      "Twelve Minutes",
      "Ori",
      "Streets of Rage",
      "Last of Us",
      "Boodborne",
      "Geenshin Impact",
      "Dragon Ball Z:KAKAROT",
      "Ghost Tsushima",
      "Naruto",
      "Overcooked",
      "Horizon",
      "Tomb Raider",
      "Uncharted",
      "Person 5 Royal",
      "Ratchet",
      "Spider-Man"
    ];

    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomGameTitle.length);

    return message.info(
      "The game you will play is: " + randomGameTitle[randomIndex] + "."
    );
  };

  return (
    <div id="video-game" className="block bgGray">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="titleHolder">
          <h2>Video Games</h2>
          <p>A list of current games</p>
          <div className="site-button-ghost-wrapper">
            <Button
              className="gameButton"
              type="primary"
              danger
              ghost
              onClick={chooseGame}
            >
              Pick for me
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Row gutter={[16, 24]}>
          {Games.map((videogame, i) => (
            <Col span={8}>
              <GameEntry
                id={i}
                key={i}
                title={videogame.title}
                imgURL={videogame.imgURL}
                description={videogame.console}
                videoID={videogame.videoID}
                setCurrentVideoID={setCurrentVideoID}
                showModal={showModal}
              />
            </Col>
          ))}
          <ModalView
            videoID={currentVideoID}
            handleClose={handleClose}
            isModalVisible={isModalVisible}
          />
        </Row>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default VideoGameSection;
```

Access the `videoID` passed via `ModalView`. You can save `gameId` instead of `videoID` to get any other info of the game Ex:`title`.
**YoutubeSection.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";

function YoutubeSection(props) {
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <ReactPlayer
        url={`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${props.videoID}`}
        muted={false}
        playing={true}
        controls={true}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default YoutubeSection;
```

**GameEntry.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Card, Button, Modal } from "antd";
import YoutubeSection from "./YoutubeSection";

const { Meta } = Card;

function GameEntry(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Card
        className="gameCard"
        hoverable
        cover={<img className="cardImg" alt={props.title} src={props.imgURL} />}
      >
        <div className="cardTitle">
          <Meta title={props.title} description={props.description} />
        </div>
        <>
          <Button
            className="trailerButton"
            type="primary"
            block
            style={{
              color: "#fff",
              borderColor: "#fff",
              backgroundColor: "#e6544f"
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              props.setCurrentVideoID(props.videoID);
              props.showModal();
            }}
          >
            Click for trailer
          </Button>
        </>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}

export default GameEntry;
```

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-dan-z0kc0?file=/src/ModalView.js